# Tabbing through the inline tag editor doesn't focus the input or allow adding new tags

Tags: bug, user-experience, keyboard, inline-tag-editor

While editing a post one can press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to go from the **Body** editor to the **Tags** input, then type letters to add a tag. For example:

> [image: demonstration of pressing tab to add a tag during normal edit]

However, when using the inline tag editor, one can press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key but not type characters to create a new tag without clicking my mouse to focus on the text input:

> [image: demonstration of pressing tab to create add a tag during inline tag edit]

Can the inline tag editor be updated so that one can press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key during inline tag editing to add a tag?

Comment: Re *"editing inline tags"*: [The 10k+ user feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/inline-tag-editor/info). A keyboard-only invoke: Tab to link *"Edit tags"* (33 tabs(!), but there are shorter ones, like `Ctrl` + `F`, `E`, `d`, `Esc` (may depend on browser configuration)—some other ones don't work due to conflict with the SE keyboard shortcuts (if enabled in user profile preferences)) → `Enter` → one `Tab` to focus in the *"Tags"* field.

Comment: *"Save Tag Edits"* and *"Cancel"* are not even in the tab order. And `Esc` doesn't work to get out of the mode.

Comment: You can get focus by pressing `Enter` (while focus is on one of the tags in the "Tags" field). But it will delete a tag...

Comment: Related script on Stack Apps: [Bring focus to inline tag editor](https://stackapps.com/q/10370/80368)